# Numba @jit and @njit giving errors

Tags: python, numba

I am iterating over x and y in a number of rows and columns and I have a 2DArray 'inarray' which holds the brushfire algorithm cost per square similar to this:

```
array[[900   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7]
      [  2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8]
      [  3   2 900   4   5   6   7   8   9]
      [  4   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10]
      [  5   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11]
      [  6   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12]
      [  7   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13]
      [  8   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14]
      [  9   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15]
      [ 10   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16]]
```

Where 900 are obstacles, 0 is the goal, and the numbers are steps costs.

From this 2DArray I want to generate a vectorfield so I implemented the code:

```
def vectorfield(inarray, goal, r, c):
    vectorarray = np.zeros((r,c), dtype=np.int32)
    for y in range(0,c):
        for x in range(0,r):
            xy = (x,y)
            neighbours = get_direction(xy, r, c)
            best_nbr = min(neighbours.keys(), key=lambda n: inarray[n])
            vectorarray[xy] = neighbours[best_nbr]

    vectorarray[goal] = -1
    return vectorarray
```

I made another 2D array to not overwrite the map so that the costs still can be referenced. Then I looped through the rows and columns, and for each point I generated directions values which are a dictionary of points:angle :

```
directions = {
    (x - 1, y + 1): 225, (x, y + 1): 180, (x + 1, y + 1): 135,
    (x - 1, y): 270,                           (x + 1, y): 90,
    (x - 1, y - 1): 315,  (x, y - 1): 0,   (x + 1, y - 1): 45,
}
```

Where each point is filtered out if it is out the map.

Then I use the min() function to get the point with the least cost in its neighbours. Finally, the value of the neighbours (angle pointing to the next square) is placed in the vectorarray.

I should say it works without the decorators

The problem is that I wanted to the @jit or @njit decorators to speed up the execution and I don't understand how to fix them.

Errors with @njit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 334, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 313, in main
        inarray = vectorfield(inarray, (0,1), w, h)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 330, in _compile_for_args
        raise e
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 307, in _compile_for_args
        return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 579, in compile
        cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
        flags=flags, locals=self.locals)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 766, in compile_extra
        return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 362, in compile_extra
        return self._compile_bytecode()
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 725, in _compile_bytecode
        return self._compile_core()
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 712, in _compile_core
        res = pm.run(self.status)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 248, in run
        raise patched_exception
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
        stage()
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 454, in stage_nopython_frontend
        self.locals)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 868, in type_inference_stage
        infer.propagate()
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 844, in propagate
        raise errors[0]
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 137, in propagate
        constraint(typeinfer)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 415, in __call__
        self.resolve(typeinfer, typevars, fnty)
      File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 450, in resolve
        raise TypingError(msg, loc=self.loc)
    numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
    Invalid usage of type(CPUDispatcher(<function get_direction at 0x105f218c8>)) with parameters ((int64 x 2), int64, int64)
     * parameterized
    File "lel1.py", line 298
    [1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function get_direction at 0x105f218c8>))
    [2] During: typing of call at /Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py (298)
```

Errors with @jit:

```
most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 259, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 65, in lower_inst
    value = self.lower_assign(inst)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 159, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(value)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 373, in lower_expr
    raise NotImplementedError(expr)
NotImplementedError: make_function(name=$const50.17, code=<code object <lambda> at 0x102295150, file "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 300>, closure=$50.15, defaults=None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 334, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 313, in main
    inarray = vectorfield(inarray, (0,1), w, h)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 307, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 658, in compile
    lifted_from=self.lifted_from)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 780, in compile_ir
    lifted_from=lifted_from)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 370, in compile_ir
    return self._compile_ir()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 732, in _compile_ir
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 712, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 248, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 625, in stage_objectmode_backend
    self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=True)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 602, in _backend
    lowered = lowerfn()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 576, in backend_object_mode
    self.flags)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 909, in py_lowering_stage
    lower.lower()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 135, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 176, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 201, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 265, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 259, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/lowering.py", line 216, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 65, in lower_inst
    value = self.lower_assign(inst)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 159, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(value)
  File "/Users/aditya/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/numba/objmode.py", line 373, in lower_expr
    raise NotImplementedError(expr)
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode backend)
make_function(name=$const50.17, code=<code object <lambda> at 0x102295150, file "/Users/aditya/Desktop/PycharmPrograms/RandomIdeas/lel1.py", line 300>, closure=$50.15, defaults=None)
File "lel1.py", line 300
[1] During: loweri
```

EDIT: 
Inarray (literally converted my inarray to list):

```
numpy.array([[900, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 2, 900, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [8, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [9, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [10, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

The get directions function is as such (I believe this is the only other necessary part to reproducing the problem after knowing inarray.)

```
@jit
def get_direction(point, rows, cols):
    (x, y) = point
    directions = {
        (x - 1, y + 1): 225, (x, y + 1): 180, (x + 1, y + 1): 135,
        (x - 1, y): 270,                       (x + 1, y): 90,
        (x - 1, y - 1): 315, (x, y - 1): 0,    (x + 1, y - 1): 45,
    }

    delete = []
    for k in directions.keys():
        if k[0] >= rows or k[0] < 0 or k[1] >= cols or k[1] < 0:
            delete.append(k)

    for i in delete:
        del directions[i]

    return directions
```

Comment: Could you create an [mcve]? Your code doesn't run as-is and one needs more than just minor modifications to make it work (I didn't succeed).

Comment: I guess the problem is just that numba doesn't support dictionaries, so you cannot use them with `njit`.

Comment: @MSeifert I have edited the problem to make it reproducable - hope this is enough

Comment: Still misses the inputs you pass to that function. I can run the version with `jit` without problems using: `get_direction((1, 2), 2, 3)`. However as said before the `njit` cannot work because dicts are not supported.